# How do I use google maps directions preview for delivery app?

Tags: android

How do I use google maps directions preview for delivery app? I noticed that instacart uses Google to get preview, how do I use it for my own app?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td3VN.jpg)

I tried Google my maps before but didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [**Google Maps API**](https://developers.google.com/maps) for implementing directions preview.